# Getting data from PostgreSQ cursor in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to call a PostgreSQL function in PHP and access the data in the cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.my_function(INOUT result_cursor refcursor, INOUT param_id numeric)
RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
  DECLARE
    TMPCURSOR REFCURSOR;
  begin
    BEGIN
      OPEN TMPCURSOR FOR
      SELECT  a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, b.c1, b.c2
      FROM table1 a, table2 b
         WHERE
        a.id = param_id
        AND a.f = b.f
      ORDER BY
        a.c1;
    END;
    result_cursor := TMPCURSOR;
    RETURN;
  end;
  $function$
;
```

This is what I've tried:

```
pg_query($conn, "BEGIN;");
pg_query($conn, "DECLARE a CURSOR FOR SELECT my_schema.my_function('a', 123);");
$result = pg_query($conn, "FETCH ALL IN a;");
print_r(pg_fetch_all($result));
pg_query($conn, "COMMIT;");
```

I get this array as a result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [my_function] => ("",123)
        )

)
```

And a similar approach:

```
pg_query($conn, "BEGIN;");
pg_query($conn, "DECLARE a CURSOR FOR SELECT * from my_schema.my_function('a', 123);");
$result = pg_query($conn, "FETCH ALL IN a;");
print_r(pg_fetch_all($result));
pg_query($conn, "COMMIT;");
```

yields this array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [result_cursor] => 
            [param_id] => 123
        )

)
```

I want to get an array with the values of the columns a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, b.c1, b.c2.

I know I can just make a query with the select inside the function, but assuming I *need* to use the function, is there a way to get the result from the cursor in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot to do all these statements in one step. You need for any SQL statement one execution from PHP side.